# OBIEE create JSON List Connection Pool File

Tags: json, obiee

I am trying to create a json file for listing the connection pools, since this should be a solution for my issue that after importinstanceservice my connectionpool data has "Replace me" values. I found this  [guide](http://allthingsorcl.blogspot.be/2015/11/obiee-12c-new-command-line-utilities.html) online which contained a script to do so. But since I'm pretty new to OBIEE and Oracle in general I can't seem to figure out what to fill in in the different field. Where do I find this uid? What's parentName (Is this the name of database in the rpd?) and so on. Has anyone already done this and can help me guide through this?

Thanks!

```
    File connPoolList.json content:
 {
"Title":"List Connection Pools",
"Conn-Pool-Info":[
{
"uid":"<uid1>",
"connPool":"<conn pool name1>",
"parentName":"<parent name1>",
"user":"<username1>",
"password":"<password1>",
"dataSource":"<data Source value1>",
"appServerName":"<app server name1>"
},
{
"uid":"<uid2>",
"connPool":"<conn pool name2>",
"parentName":"<parent name2>",
"user":"<username2>",
"password":"<password2>",
"dataSource":"<data Source value2>",
"appServerName":"<app server name2>"
}
],
"Variables-In-Conn-Pool":[
{
"uid":"<uid1>",
"variable":"<VARNAME1>",
"value":"'<VALUE1>'"
},
{
"uid":"<uid2>",
"variable":"<VARNAME2>",
"value":"'<VALUE2>'"
}  
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've configured your Connection Pools, and then use [`listConnectionPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEMG/GUID-42FA5E06-F29B-411D-9424-3276368F7188.htm#conn_list_pool_cmd), you'll see what values you need to supply and which can be left as is.

BTW [this article](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/source-control-and-automated-code-deployment-options-for-obiee/) will probably help you.

Comment: This was an awesome article and was a great help. Thanks Robin!